# Error in Python3 when assigning raw string to a variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
src = r'C:\Users\'
```

I keep getting an error when assigning the above string to a variable (SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal). It has something to do with the last backslash. I would have thought making it a raw string would prevent this. What is causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly do “u” and “r” string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals). From the accepted answer: in a raw string literal, a backslash is "taken as meaning 'just a backslash' (_except when it comes right before a quote that would otherwise terminate the literal_)".

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) states

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the
>   backslash remains in the result; (...) Specifically, a raw literal
>   cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the
>   following quote character).

Instead, you can just do `src = 'C:\\Users\\'`.